# How to set combobox default value in c++

Tags: c++, combobox

I have combobox that need to have default value and that value to be written in to a file. Below I added some items to a combobox

```
    comboBox1->Items->Add("red");
    comboBox1->Items->Add("blue");
```

with a code below I write a line into a text file with selected combobox element. And in the text file you should see written word `blue`

```
sw->WriteLine("\"grey\") some blah \"" + comboBox1->SelectedIndex = 1 + "\" ");
```

But I get `C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value` error

Comment: I guess that SelectedIndex is the index of selected item in your combobox. You can not assign to it

Comment: What type is `comboBox1`? Are you using Qt or some other library?

Comment: I don't know I just draged from the toolbox in  visual studio

Comment: What toolbox? From Visual Studio? Qt Creator? Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are combining setting of the index with building a string?
comboBox1->SelectedIndex = 1 should set the active item to be the second entry in the combo box.
The error message indicates it wants a long value. You are not providing that.

Comment: And how should that look like ?

Comment: Try this on a solo line:
`(comboBox1->SelectedIndex = 1)`

Comment: Yes guessed that might work on solo line how to pass that value in to file?

Comment: Not using c++ but this should work:
`comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString()`